# Python: Replace different words in a string using matching array values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a task where there is a string with text markers that need to be replaced with a given array with matching key value pairs. The key in the array must match with the markers in the string and replace it with the key's value.

Ex:

> txt = "Hello #NAME#, Today is #DATE# and your subscription is ending
>   in #NO_OF_DAYS# days."
>
> mydict = {"#NAME#":"David", "#DATE#":"01/14/2020", "#NO_OF_DAYS#":"10"}

The final text that must return after the replacement is,

> "Hello David, Today is 01/14/2020 and your subscription is ending in
>   10 days."

How can I get this done in the simplest way?

Comment: You should show how you're "working" on this task

Comment: Python already has [some kind of template language builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), and Django has it's own full-blown template language too. Why not use one of them instead ???

Comment: this seem like a simple python question , not involving Django at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the dictionary's items and use `replace()` over `txt`

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    txt = txt.replace(key, val)
```

Note: it is not a good idea to use `dict` as a variable name since it is a builtin type in python

Comment: `dict` is NOT a keyword - else it could not be used as an identifier actually -, it's a builtin type. But it's indeed not a good idea to use it as a variable name - and not only because it will shadows the builtin type, but also (and more importantly) because it does describe the type of the variable, not it's purpose / use / content. `replacements` would be a more meaningful name. Or `context` (often used in templating languages).

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in the case of keys such as `REPLACEMENT_1`, `REPLACEMENT_10`... it will add `0`'s to a lot of text. The replacement would have to be done in order from longest to shortest.